# How to send server side notifications using rails & aws to phonegap device

Tags: cordova, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm searching for a solution for sending server side notifications from rails to a cordova app for a certain set of devices at a particular point in time.

Let's say users place bids for an item. Each time a bid is placed on that item, every user who posted a bid needs to be notified. The notification needs to take the form of a JS callback.

Now I'm digging through examples of AWS SNS but I fear it doesn't fit my purpose. The flow on AWS SNS is roughly this one

```
Platform_applicaton --> Platform_endpoint --> subscription for a topic



require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'


sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(
  access_key_id: 'X',
  secret_access_key: 'X',
  region: 'X',
  ssl_ca_bundle: 'c:\tmp\ca-bundle.crt'
)

# create platform application
platform_app = sns.create_platform_application(
  # required
  name: "parking-space-web",
  # required
  platform: "GCM",
  # required
  attributes:
    { :PlatformCredential => "google_api_key" ,
      :PlatformPrincipal => "" }
)

puts platform_app['platform_application_arn']

#create endpoint
endpoint = sns.create_platform_endpoint(
  # required
  platform_application_arn: platform_app['platform_application_arn'],
  # required
  token: "app1"
)

# subscribe to topic
subscription = sns.subscribe(
  # required
  topic_arn: "arn:aws:topic:arn",
  # required
  #I can choose whatever protocol I want but the physical notification will    just be a call made via that specific protocol ( http/email ).
  protocol: "application", 
  endpoint: endpoint['endpoint_arn'],
)
```

How is that useful to me? I'm publishing a message via `http/email` which is plainly sent to multiple `http/email` subscribers. If I needed that I would simply make the `http/email` requests myself. What's the advantage of SNS?

I figure that the real deal with SNS is the 'application' protocol which uses the vendor API keys ( GCM, APNS, ADM, etc. ) to send notification to/from the specific platforms, but that doesn't help me much when using cordova. I have to install a custom plugin to intercept those notifications. Not bad, but I figure there's a cleaner solution.

Given what I found it seems that [AWS SQS is the best solution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Publishing_to_a_topic).

1. Can AWS SQS deliver messages to multiple recipients (topic-like)?
2. Do messages persist and get delivered when client comes back online?
3. Is it feasible to create one queue for each item, and publish a message each time a bid is placed? This will result in a LOT of queues being created.

Comment: So what's your question? SNS or SQS.

Comment: The questions are 1,2,3 above. And if SQS is not the solution how can I use SNS to fullfil the client-side notifications requirements

Comment: Isn't there a simple way for a JS client to subscribe to an SNS topic and receive notifications (via a JS callback on client side) when a message is published to that topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. No, that is not how you use SQS. Sure its possible to have lots and lots of clients poll a queue looking for a message, but that's now how SQS is designed to be used. SQS doesn't deliver messages, clients poll for the messages.
2. SQS Message persist until they expire (which I beleive the max is 14 days). SNS has configurable retry policies, but the max lifetime is 60 minutes.
3. Yes its possible, but no you probably don't want to do that.

Not 100% certain of you restraints, but of the technologies you have mentioned, my guess is that SNS mobile push http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html is probably closest to what you need.

Edit: I have not used Cordova, but this article may help as well:
https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx17CAREHZUWLH9/Getting-started-with-the-Cordova-Push-Notifications-Plugin-for-Amazon-Fire-OS

Comment: OK, seems SNS mobile push seems the way to go. I'm surprised though there isn't any simple way to get client side JS notifications. And yes there are the platform specific notifications (like ADM that you mentioned), but I wanted to avoid using them. They require installing plugin and cannot be tested without deploying to the actual device

Comment: @victor am working on the same problem you faced. am wondering how you managed to implement client side notifications of an event?

Comment: I think the best way to go is the traditional notifications that ios/android expose by default. Your user will get s notification on his screen if he is not using the app, or system will call a listener on your side if user has slyke app open.